# Numbervalue function in Excel not working

Tags: excel, function, numbers

I'm using Excel 2013 and when I try to use the `NUMBERVALUE` function I constantly get the `#VALUE!` error. It doesn't matter if I use it simply as:

```
=NUMBERVALUE("")
```

I still get the error.

If I change it to `VALUE` Function only, then it works fine.

Any ideas where might the issue come from?

Comment: Here it returns `0`.  Perhaps something in your excel environment?  Try starting Excel in safe mode.  Also, what are your locale decimal and group separators when you examine your Windows REgional Settings dialog?

Comment: Yep, it was because of this. For decimal separator I had "." and for group as well. I changed it to "," and now it works.

Comment: Glad you've got it working.

Answer (score 0):

### #VALUE!

Occurs if either:

The [decimal_separator] occurs more than once in the supplied [text] argument;

The [group_separator] occurs after the [decimal_separator] within the supplied [text] argument;

Any of the supplied arguments are not valid.

Comment: taken from http://www.excelfunctions.net/excel-numbervalue-function.html I use this site for any new functions I've not used before

Comment: Neither of those should be an issue with the formula he showed in his question `=NUMBERVALUE("") `

Comment: " " is not valid, it must be NULL value, or lack of a value i guess, it is not the same as 1-1 = 0, this is just a guess i'm not 100% sure

Comment: I agree with there being a difference.  But `""` is what he posted.  That is not the same as `" "`  And, in 2016, they both return `0`

Comment: solved. it was because of the regional settings. Thanks to Ron I found the problem.